Is pulling out existential quantifier from an implication constructively valid?
I was unable to prove the following "obvious" schema of puling out a quantifier constructively:
$$(\phi\rightarrow\exists x\psi(x))\rightarrow \exists x(\phi \rightarrow\psi(x))$$
The proof is straight forward if it can be assumed that $\phi \lor\neg \phi$. The proof of the converse is also straight-forward.
Background: This property could be used to prove the standard Axiom of Choice (ACL) implies LEM as given in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/, and I wonder if this holds.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Consider the following Kripke model with two 'worlds' $0 < 1$:

$\phi$ is false, and $ψ$ fails for all $x_0$ in the domain $M_0$
$\phi$ is true, and a new domain element $x_1$ has been added on which $ψ$ holds, but it still fails for all the $x_0$.

In this model $\phi → ∃x. ψ(x)$ is true

$0 \nVdash \phi$, so $(0 \Vdash \phi) → (0 \Vdash ∃x. ψ(x))$ holds vacuously
$1 \Vdash ψ(x_1)$, so $(1 \Vdash \phi) → (1 \Vdash ∃x. ψ(x))$
So, $∀w. (w \Vdash \phi) → (w \Vdash ∃x. ψ(x))$. Therefore $∀ w. w \Vdash φ → ∃x. ψ(x)$

However, $∃x. (\phi → ψ(x))$ is false.

$1 \Vdash \phi$, but $1 \nVdash ψ(x_0)$, so $1 \nVdash \phi → ψ(x_0)$ when $x_0 \in M_0$
But, for $0 \Vdash ∃x. \phi → ψ(x)$ to hold, there must be $x_0 \in M_0$ such that $1 \Vdash \phi → ψ(x_0)$
Ergo, $0 \nVdash ∃x. φ → ψ(x)$


Is it then correct that the classical axiom of choice (ACL) implies LEM, given the proof uses this additional property? Is there a way of patching the proof with some other generic property?

I don't see how ACL at your link could imply excluded middle without further assumptions about what is being modeled. For instance, if you just put that in some kind of arithmetic, where the individuals are supposed to be natural numbers, then ACL is countable choice, which has constructive models.

@MarkSaving could you give a reference for that proof?

@NaïmFavier Unfortunately, I was wrong; this scheme doesn’t hold over IZF. Define $Q(S)$ to be the statement “There exists $X \subseteq S$ such that any two elements of $X$ are equal and $X$ is inhabited iff $S$ is.” Over IZF, the scheme is equivalent to saying $\forall S, Q(S)$. However, it is consistent with IZF that $\neg \forall S \subseteq {0, 1}, Q(S)$. This is not too hard to see by considering $Sh(\mathbb{R})$ for instance; I can provide further details if required.
My apologies for the error.

@MarkSaving I'm not following; let's continue in chat.

I shall add a supplementary note to Doel's answer that may be of interest.
At first sight, it might seem counter-intuitive, but the given formula is valid in classical logic.
Actually, its converse is a theorem of intuitionistic logic:
$$\exists x(\phi\rightarrow\psi(x))\rightarrow(\phi\rightarrow\exists x\psi(x))$$
(see the chapter on intuitionistic logic in Dirk van Dalen's Logic and Structure).
Contraposition is retained in intuitionistic logic; thus,
$$\neg(\phi\rightarrow\exists x\psi(x))\rightarrow\neg\exists x(\phi \rightarrow\psi(x))$$
is also valid. Since this and the given formula cannot be valid together, the given one is invalid in intuitionistic logic.
We notice that $\exists x(\phi\rightarrow\psi(x))$ would be a prenex normal form of $(\phi\rightarrow\exists x\psi(x))$. Hence, the given formula constitutes an example for the fact that not every predicate formula has an intuitionistically equivalent prenex normal form.

Thank you for the note! Why can not the formulas be valid together?

If it were valid, its contrapositive would have to be valid as well. However, the form $\neg\neg A\rightarrow A$ is invalid in intuitionistic logic.
